# Adding an iFrame when a boostrap modal is visible with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, youtube, bootstrap-modal

I'd like to add a youtube embed to a modal when the modal becomes visible on screen via jQuery as I have multiple modals on screen that affect page load time significantly, i just want to load the video when that specific modal is visible on screen.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $(modalID).on('show',function(){
       $('.player').html('<iframe width="560" height="315" src="embed code" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');//iframe class
});  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out for anyone wondering...
Obviously you need an iFrame without an initial src attribute inside it like  width.. height=... and the rest of the attributes

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
 $(modalID).on('show',function(){
       $(iFrame).attr('src', youtube embed src);//add the youtube embed source
});  
});
```